# How to route by header in DB-less Kong

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I'm using Kong without database and I need to route request based on request header: `x-forwarded-host`.

I'm referring to the doc: https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/route-by-header/

But it doesn't provide examples for the "without database" version.

Then I noticed that route-by-header is not in the compatible plugin list in https://docs.konghq.com/1.4.x/db-less-and-declarative-config/

So my questions are:

- Does DB-less Kong support route-by-header plugin?
- Is there any way to route by request header in DB-less Kong?

Updates:

- Just found out that the route-by-header plugin is probably not compatible with DB-less Kong, and it's for enterprise subscription only.
- Since Kong 1.3, a feature has been added to allow routing by request header in the Routes definition
  https://docs.konghq.com/1.3.x/proxy/#request-header
- But it doesn't provide examples for the declarative config format for DB-less Kong. So I need to figure out the correct format for this feature.

Resolved:
In the declarative configuration file, add:

```
    routes:
      - name: my-routes
        headers:
          x-forwarded-host: ["xxx.xxx.com"]
        paths: ["/xxx/api"]
```

This will match the route based on both headers and paths

Comment: did try out any code?

Comment: I'm glad I found this. Thanks for sharing. IT's frustrating that the documentation is missing examples for DB-less mode quite frequently.

Comment: Did this work I really want this feature?